# Should I use the domain registrar or the web hosting name servers?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver, dns-servers

Let's say that I have the following website `example.com`, the domain registrar is provided by one company and the website hosting is provided by another.

- do I use the registrar name servers e.g `ns.exampleA.com`
- or do I use the web host name servers e.g `ns.exampleB.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your hosting account is configured to use the domain `example.com` (presumably specified when you setup the hosting account), then you just need to change the NAMESERVERs at your domain registrar to point to your hosting provider (ie. change `ns.exampleA.com` to `ns.exampleB.com`).

The DNS will then be handled by your hosting provider, which should already have been configured for you when the hosting account was created (including mailserver etc.).

Comment: Well it could also be ns1.hostingcompany.com and ns2 or anything else for that matter.

Comment: @Anagio: ns.a.com and ns.b.com are just example nameservers given by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can change the name servers doesn't mean you should.

It's a mistake by many that they believe changing the name servers to that of their hosting is better when really its a mixed debate and depends on the DNS server reliability. What you find with Domain Registrars these days is they use very reliable DNS servers along with built in DNS management while years ago you had to pay for this DNS management therefor changing the name servers was ideal.

If your domain registrar has its own why not give them a try or least take a look at there SLA uptime policy.

Changing A Records is alot easier and faster when moving website from host to host, as changing name servers takes longer to update globally while records do not.

My 2 Cents, Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I use 3rd party DNS hosting.    It doesn't have to be tied to either your domain registrar or your web host.   DNS hosting is so inexpensive ($20/year for multiple domains) that it often makes sense to look elsewhere for features and reliability.

Comment: Yep, often 3rd party DNS hosting is better, more features and better reliability. DynDNS comes to mind, but they are expensive but then again, purely depends on how critical your DNS is, a site being offline for a few seconds can cause some companies to lose millions, but for some a little downtime in a blue moon doesn't mean they lose money, or leads.

Answer (score 0):

I use cloudflare for my DNS management. It gives me flexibility and much faster than hosting providers DNS managements sys.